# Is it possible to design a gesture for letters like t?

Tags: android, gestures

Currently I'm building an android app that displays a letter for the user to input and implementing the users input with Gestures. I've used GestureBuilder on my emulator to design the gesture alphabet but as Gestures are built on one finger stroke can gesture builder be used to correctly create gestures for letters like t,f,i,A,E etc.

If not, can anyone recommend anything I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Sure-  write your own view and do touch handling completely on your own.  Don't use the built in GestureDetector, which is extremely limiting.

Or better yet you may want to search for an open source handwriting detection library-  writing your own is a non-trivial amount of work.